# Copy / Reflection.Emit'ting static arrays

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit, emit

I'm attempting to copy a static initializers from one DLL to another.

If you have a static array initializer in C#, you get something like this:

```
.class private auto ansi <PrivateImplementationDetails>{0D3E8B0E-F218-435F-989D-9D04F550A786}
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
    .field assembly static valuetype <PrivateImplementationDetails>{0D3E8B0E-F218-435F-989D-9D04F550A786}/__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=120 $$method0x6000060-1 = ((binary data))
```

I found the easiest way to read this data to use this:

```
int size = field.FieldType.StructLayoutAttribute.Size;
byte[] data = new byte[size];
RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(data, field.FieldHandle);
```

Basically this will give you the 'binary data' that's mentioned above.

**Question 1**: What will happen with `Dictionary`'s? Will this still work? I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly happens here (it seems to be hidden from decompilation)...

I've already found that the GUID to use in the implementation details is the version ID in the `ModuleBuilder`. Using the other explicit field information that means you should be able to copy the data.

**Question 2**: How can you write the data back in another `ModuleBuilder` / `FieldBuilder` using Reflection.Emit ?

--

Version? .NET 4.5 (VS2013 default)

There seems to be confusion about the `Dictionary`'s that pop up. I did some digging in my code, and they seem to pop up as [string->int] dictionaries, used to resolve switch/case statements.

For example, see they can be found in mscorlib.dll v4.0.30319.18444. In Reflector they look like this:

```
.field assembly static class System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<string, int32> $$method0x6003a20-1
```

As for why: I'm changing DLL's before executing some tests on them. Ironically the reason why I want this is because I don't want to mess with the implementation details :-) and because multiple instances will probably give trouble.

In other words, I basically just want to copy them all 'as-if they were a binary blob' if they have fancy data like this, regardless of types etc, while preserving the name. Since IL and data is treated the same way in different DLL's, this should always be possible regardless of the compiler IMHO, right?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. It is an implementation detail. You shouldn't rely on that; it could be changed any time. Are you creating dynamic assembly?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes I know, but in my case that's not a problem: I'm attempting to make changes to existing assemblies (any only for testing, not for production purposes). I'm writing back the assemblies to disk (AssemblyBuilder.Save), so I suppose that's not a real 'dynamic assembly'.

Comment: @atlaste This "thing" is used only for arrays, from what I can see, not for `Dictionary<,>` initialization. See http://goo.gl/yIT2GY . Not even for a `List<int>` { .... } initialization

Comment: That's ok. But without more context it's hard to answer. I don't even understand what you're trying to achieve why you need this etc. But answer for your first question is: no, Dictionary won't work that way. It will be compiled into `Dictionary.Add` method calls.

Comment: `.class private auto ansi <PrivateImplementationDetails>{0D3E8B0E-F218-435F-989D-9D04F550A786}` This seems to be false with roslyn: in the example it is only named `<PrivateImplementationDetails>` (http://goo.gl/yIT2GY)

Comment: @xanatos interesting... in ILSpy they do pop up for large string `switch`/`case` blocks; they don't pop up in your tool. (with strings as keys in the `case` obviously)

Comment: @atlaste It is not because of the decompiling tool, but because of the compiler. That online compiler is new C#6.0 compiler(roslyn). New compiler may behave different(you just saw it); that's what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, that's why I want to just copy them all as binary blob. Regardless of the compiler, the DLL specification should stay the same after all; so that way implementation details shouldn't get in the way.

Comment: Okay, small update: `SetData` seems to set the array data. The proper way to call that is to use `DefineInitializedData`. As for the hidden `Dictionary`'s... I'm still figuring that out.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of fiddling this seems to be the way it works:

... for each field in `<PrivateImplementationDetails>`:

- Either value types or reference types are used.
- Value types can carry data, reference types cannot. Reference types are initialized before they are used (as volatile statics, f.ex. in the same scope as they are used).

Getting data from a value type (`field.FieldType.IsValueType`) can be done with the `RuntimeHelpers` call:

```
int size = GetManagedSize(field.FieldType);
byte[] data = new byte[size];

RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(data, field.FieldHandle);

FieldBuilder mappedField = myType.DefineInitializedData(
    field.Name, data, field.Attributes);
```

with:

```
public static int GetManagedSize(Type type)
{
    var method = new DynamicMethod("GetManagedSizeImpl", typeof(uint), new Type[0], 
        GetType().Assembly, false);

    ILGenerator gen = method.GetILGenerator();

    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Sizeof, type);
    gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    var func = (Func<uint>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<uint>));
    return checked((int)func());
}
```

If it's a reference type, you don't need to do anything, as these are initialized as volatile statics when they are used.

After this, you need to ensure you use the generated fieldinfo's instead of the original fields; they will contain the same data. As for references, these are initialized as `null`.

Obviously you don't want to mess around with the implementation details themselves or the way they are used...

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my day !! …